# Why extra blank lines appeared?

Tags: shell-script

I have a space delimited data out from a program in horizontal:

```
0 2 32 323 443 ...
```

I created a shell script to convert horizontal listed file to vertical to sort it out :

```bsh
filename=/tmp/vList
colcount=$(wc -w < "$1")
counter=1
sortResult=0

while [ "$counter" -le "$colcount" ] 
do
cat "$1" | cut -d " " -f"$counter">>"$filename"
counter=$((counter+1))
done
```

It worked, however it creates a vertical list including blank lines between each values of the horizontal list:

```
0

2

32

323
```

Why are there blank lines, how can I prevent them?

[Edit] After IsaaC's suggestion, I saw that my question is duplicate of previous one, similar,even same answers were there, so I must close this question. I am appreciated to all contributors.

Comment: What is the contents of the "$1" file? If it has blank/non-matched line then that could be what you're seeing. Also, you can replace the whole `counter=$((counter+1))` with just `((counter++))`.

Comment: Is there a blank line in your input file? Is it the 1st line? Side note: the script reads its input multiple times, this is far from optimal.

Comment: @CR $1 file content is the list of the data as I wrote in question; for instance 02 32 232 323 ...

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski  : YES ! Thanks, exactly the first line was blank. Thanks that solved. How can I improve multiple read issue? Do you means storing it to a variable?

Comment: You can achieve the same thing with simply `cat inputlist.txt | tr ' ' '\n' > /tmp/vList`. No multiple reads. No need for a script with a loop at all.

Comment: @frabjous Leave the `cat` alone. :) `<inputlist.txt tr …`

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski LOL. Gotta get out of that habit. Go ahead and give me the "useless use of cat award".

Comment: Inspect your file for trailing blanks: `od -bc /tmp/vList`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `tr`:

```
tr ' ' '\n' < file
```

For example:

```
% cat file
0 2 32 323 443
% tr ' ' '\n' < file
0
2
32
323
443
```

Comment: Your code will still convert trailing and embedded spaces to extraneous blank lines. Test with `"0 2 32   323 443      "`.

Comment: @waltinator That's easily fixed by using `tr` with its `-s` option.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's a pure shell script you want?

```bsh
grep -o '\S\+' input.file
```

or

```bsh
sed 's/[[:blank:]\n]\+/\n/g' input.file
```

or

```bsh
awk -v RS='([[:blank:]\n]+)' '1' input.file
```

or

```bsh
awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i }' input.file
```

...is probably more accurate.

Comment: `/tmp/vList` is the output file in the OP's script, not the input file.

Comment: Right. I'll remove the reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pne "s/ /\n/g" filename
```

output

```
0
2
32
323
443
```

Answer (score -1):

A better way:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="/tmp/vList"
for i in $(cat "$filename") ; do
    echo "$i"
fi
```

Comment: `/tmp/vList` is the output file in the OP's script, not the input file.